# C#: Random.NextDouble method stalling out application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, random, mono

I'm receiving some inconsistent behavior from the `Random.NextDouble()`.

Regularly, the console would freeze and the cpu usage would increase dramatically until I closed it down. I ran the debugger and found that the cause of the freezing was `Random.NextDouble()`. I added some lines for debugging purposes, but the code is as follows:

```
        double generateCatenationRate()
        {
            double catenation = 999.999; //random value to see if it pops up down there
            double uniformValue;
            double int_covalence = covalence.original;
            double dist = int_covalence - 4;


            int counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                counter++;
                uniformValue = utils.getRandomDouble(); //goes bad here!
                if (uniformValue <= 0.15)
                {
                    catenation = Math.Abs(utils.normalize(dist, 0, 4)) + uniformValue;

                    if (catenation < 0 || catenation > 1)
                    {
                        if (counter > 10000)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Went nuclear!");
                            break; //break so console doesn't stall out
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Took "+counter+" iterations.");
                return 1 - catenation;
        }
```

And:

```
        public static double getRandomDouble()
        {
            Init();
            return random.NextDouble();
        }
```

Lastly:

```
        private static void Init()
        {
            if (random == null) random = new Random();
        }
```

It typically does not stall out, but running it several times successively produces output such as:

```
Took 4 iterations.
Took 3 iterations
Took 3 iterations.
Took 23 iterations.
Took 12 iterations.
Took 4 iterations.
Went nuclear!
Took 10007 iterations.
```

Can anyone explain why `Random.NextDouble()` occasionally seems to create an infinite loop? Looking around, I suspect it has something to do with how the values are seeded, but any insight would be appreciated; would love to fix this issue.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** `covalence.original` is always an integer between 1 and 8 (inclusive). `normalize()` performs min-max normalization, producing a number from 0-1 based on an input and a range. Neither of these seem to contribute to the problem, however.

Comment: What does your `normalize()` method do?

Comment: And what's the value of `covalence.original`?

Comment: You can use the debugger (set a breakpoint on the `Console.WriteLine("Went nuclear!");`  line to inspect the values of `dist` and `catenation ` and possible find the flaw in your method.

Comment: Sorry about that -- see edits

Comment: Why not print the value of `uniformValue` when you do `Console.WriteLine("Went nuclear!");` ? Then you'll know what to test it with under the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly then the value of `dist` and `utils.normalize(dist, 0, 4)` never changes.
So if `int_covalence = 8` then `dist = 4` and `utils.normalize(dist, 0, 4) = 1`, correct?

Since the chance of generating `0.0` is pretty small, that will make `catenation` virtually always greater than `1` and the check `if (catenation < 0 || catenation > 1)` always true.

Comment: I left some code out, but `dist = 4` exactly 12% of the time, so sometimes I just wouldn't notice that whenever `utils.normalize(dist, 0, 4) = 1` it exploded. Thanks for pointing that out -- I need to stop trying to program past 1AM :/

Answer (score 2):

why not just generate the samples directly rather than using rejection sampling?

```
    public static double generateCatenationRate(Random rng, double coval_norm) {
        double low = Math.abs(coval_norm) + 0.15;
        double delta = 1. - low;
        if (delta < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("impossible given covalence");
        }
        return low + delta * rng.nextDouble();
    }
```

where `coval_norm` is whatever you get back from `utils.normalize`.  if we write it this way we get visibility of the "impossible" condition and can do something about it, rather than just looping.